# How do I change input field value the way it doesn't run through the whole Redux state update cycle every time it is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange, redux

I have a component that has an input field bound to the application state, like this

```
import {updateTitle} from '../actions/sales';

class Sale extends Component {
  onTitleChange(event) {
    const {value} = event.target;
    const {id} = this.props;

    this.props.updateTitle(id, value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        placeholder="The Title"
        value={this.props.title}
        onChange={::this.onTitleChange} />
    );
  }
}

export default connect(({sales}) => ({
  title: sales.title
}), {
  updateTitle
}))(Sale);
```

but a lot heavier in markup.

Everything is nice except that when I try to type something into this field fast, the browser lags significantly since every input change, which implies every key press, runs through the whole loop from event handler, to action creator, to the actual action, to the reducer, to the store update, to component props update and render. It's super slow. Is there any way to optimize that?

Am I missing something obvious?

---

I tried using debounced function passed as `onChange` prop value but, this way, the app state wouldn't update at all. I also tried using component-level state and `setState` along with app-level state but I think this approach contradicts the idea of Redux and therefore shouldn't be used.

Comment: The `onchange` event should only fire when the input is blurred, and the value has changed, not on *"every key press"* ?

Comment: Nope, it fires on every change, i.e. every key press or other change made in the field (for example, cut or paste). It's React event, not DOM event.

Comment: Then maybe you should be using the `onBlur` event instead, so it doesn't fire on every keystroke

Answer (score 1):

React components can be [controlled or uncontrolled](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html). A controlled input receives its value as a prop and fires an event handler for each change in the value. An uncontrolled control keeps the user input in the local state and fires event handlers for changes.

Your input is currently controlled, but if you'd like to keep changes more local, why not make it uncontrolled? You can then call updateTitle in the onBlur event when the user is done typing, or debounce the onChange event to call updateTitle less often while the user is typing.

Comment: In fact, I ended up using `onBlur`, but that's not the panacea. Yes, I found out that using component-level state, i.e. having the component as uncontrolled, isn't a bad idea and definitely not an anti-pattern. Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options. The first: try connecting to the redux store closer to the input component (so less components that aren't affected by the value update on the change)

Generally though we store the intermediate values in the parent component state, and either flush the value occasionally (like a normal debounce) to the redux store, or do it on something like onBlur. So update the value in state on every change and flush the value to the store occasionally. It involves more care to make sure the values are in-sync but those are some of the trade-offs for optimizing hot paths.

Comment: The problem comes when I want to format the value of this input field, say, with `moment#format`. If the value of the field is `02/16/2016` and I delete the last character, it becomes `02/16/0201` and cursor jumps to the end. It's completely impossible for a human to change day or month then. And `onBlur` doesn't help in such case, unfortunately, because to use it, I would have to change `value` prop to `defaultValue` and manually track changes.

Comment: Although, within the scope of this question, you answer is quite helpful.